# How to date range filter table by using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have a data table variable, ' table', shown below. I want to do date range filtering with this table. I am using Date Range Picker to select start and end dates.

I did try the method below, but if I want to clear filtering after that, it's not clearing.

```js
table = $('table[data-table-name="dt-asset-history"]').DataTable({
  columns: [

    {
      title: 'Date',
      data: 'EventDate',
      class: 'essential dt-nowrap',
      render: dataTableService.parseDateColumn,
      type: 'formatteddate'
    },
    {
      title: 'Events',
      data: 'EventData',
      class: 'essential'
    }
  ],
  order: [
    [0, 'desc']
  ],
  autoWidth: false,
  dom: 't',
  processing: true,
  bDestroy: true,
  useFloater: false,
  paging: false,
  isResponsive: true,
  "order": []
});

// Date Range Picker


var start = moment().subtract(29, 'days');
var end = moment();

function cb(start, end) {
  $('#reportrange span').html(start.format('DD - MMMM - YYYY') + ' - ' + end.format('DD - MMMM - YYYY'));
}
cb(start, end);
$('#reportrange').daterangepicker({
      "showDropdowns": true,
      ranges: {
        'Today': [moment(), moment()],
        'Yesterday': [moment().subtract(1, 'days'), moment().subtract(1, 'days')],
        'Last 7 Days': [moment().subtract(6, 'days'), moment()],
        'Last 30 Days': [moment().subtract(29, 'days'), moment()],
        'This Month': [moment().startOf('month'), moment().endOf('month')],
        'Last Month': [moment().subtract(1, 'month').startOf('month'), moment().subtract(1, 'month').endOf('month')]
      }
    },
    function(selectedStart, selectedEnd, label) {
      cb(selectedStart, selectedEnd);
      console.log('New date range selected: ' + selectedStart.format('DD - MMMM - YYYY') + ' to ' + selectedEnd.format('DD - MMMM - YYYY') + ' (predefined range: ' + label + ')');


      // Filtering table
      table.search.push(
        function(settings, data, dataIndex) {
          var min = selectedStart;
          var max = selectedEnd;
          var date = new Date(data[0]);

          if (
            (min === null && max === null) ||
            (min === null && date <= max) ||
            (min <= date && max === null) ||
            (min <= date && date <= max)
          ) {
            console.log(data)
            return true;
          }
          return false;
        }
      );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.13.1/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.13.1/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.4/moment.min.js" integrity="sha512-CryKbMe7sjSCDPl18jtJI5DR5jtkUWxPXWaLCst6QjH8wxDexfRJic2WRmRXmstr2Y8SxDDWuBO6CQC6IE4KTA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please add relevant HTML and frameworks  in a [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution by using the function below.

```js
// Filtering table
$.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(
    function (settings, data, dataIndex) {
        var min = selectedStart;
        var max = selectedEnd;
        var date = new Date(data[0]);

        if (
            (min === null && max === null) ||
            (min === null && date <= max) ||
            (min <= date && max === null) ||
            (min <= date && date <= max)
        ) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
);
table.draw();
$.fn.dataTable.ext.search.pop();
```